# Recommended way of getting student assignments in Google Classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

Trying to get all **assignments for a given student** but cannot find a reliable (fast) way to do it.

It seems like the only way would be:

1. Get the student courses via [courses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list)
2. Loop through the courses list and call [courses.courseWork.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) for each

Say that on average a student has 10 courses, then 10 requests have to be made. But this takes a while and is kind of overkill...

I would like to know if I am missing something, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are the user who posted the last comment in this [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122098806#comment7). Unfortunately the method you described is the only way.

For someone who faces the same issue, in the Feature Request, you can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the Request.

Comment: I clicked on the star please include this feature in other to call less times to the API

Comment: Just ckicked star as well. I hope it comes soon, as today it is taking +10 seconds on a school app to load assignments which is a big pitfall.